# How can I make it so that my program asks again for an input after encountering the 'try' and 'except' part of my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My goal is to have the program automatically prompt for another input if the user inputs non integers and prints 'Must enter integer'. How can I do this instead of having to restart the program over and over again? Also apologies if the code is not easy on the eye, this is my first time asking for help on stackoverflow. The first of many questions.

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number // 2)
        return number // 2

    elif number % 2 == 1:
        result = (3 * number + 1) 
        print(result)
        return result

    n = input('Give me a number: ') 
    try:    
        while n != 1: 
            n = collatz(int(n))
    except ValueError:
        print('Must enter integer.')
        n = collatz(int(n))
```

Comment: Just add do/while loop and breaknit when all is fine

Comment: @DurianDragon I think the indentation is wrong.. can you edit the question to correct it

Answer (score -3):

Just a quick example how to fix try/except. You can work it into your code:

def collatz(number):

```
if number % 2 == 0:
    print(number // 2)
    return number // 2

elif number % 2 == 1:
    result = (3 * number + 1) 
    print(result)
    return result

n = input('Give me a number: ') 
try:    
    while n != 1: 
        n = collatz(int(n))
except ValueError:
    print('Must enter integer.')
    n = collatz(int(n))
```

try:
    collatz(g)
except NameError:
    print('Must be an interger')
    print('Example collatz(7) ', collatz(7))